# Licensing a Javadoc JAR file

Tags: licensing, java, documentation

What are the commons practices for licensing a Javadoc JAR file?

Since the Javadoc is automatically generated, is it legally possible to license it under a project-specific license?

Otherwise, how to license the project-specific contents that are included in the Javadoc?

For information, I'm using Gradle as a build tool, it generates the Javadoc as a build task and I would put the license file in the META-INF folder of the Javadoc JAR.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement and found a solution - see https://github.com/apache/poi/commit/e66486bc8a22c92ad7a21befc452e7786611fdcb

```
javadocJar {
    metaInf {
        from("$projectDir/../legal/LICENSE")
        from("$projectDir/../legal/NOTICE")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the code is simpler than what I used to do.
Do you also have hints about the legal aspect of licensing Javadoc generated files ?